# How to save list attributes to dbcontext in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have been trying to store default ApplicationUser data to UserTable instance. However, the data doesn't seem to be stored.
Firstly, UserTable class is as follows:

```
namespace OA2.Model
{
    public class UserTable
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserTableId { get; set; }
        public UserTable()
        {
            ApplicationUsers = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
        }
        [InverseProperty("UserList")]
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I've tried to seed some ApplicationUser data when the project is launched. However, the ApplicationUsers attribute doesn't seem to be saved no matter what I've tried. Here is the code I've tried (with commented segment as well).

```
public class UserInfoRepository: IUserInfo
{
    private readonly PDAContext _context;

    public UserInfoRepository(PDAContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        if (_context.UserTables.Count() == 0)
        {
            var userTable = new UserTable();
            _context.Add(new ApplicationUser { UserList = userTable, Id = "1", UserName = "Taki", Email = "test1@gmail.com", PasswordHash = "password1", UserRole = "Super" });
            _context.Add(new ApplicationUser { UserList = userTable, Id = "2", UserName = "Akshdeep", Email = "test2@gmail.com", PasswordHash = "password2", UserRole = "Major" });
            _context.Add(new ApplicationUser { UserList = userTable, Id = "3", UserName = "Jin", Email = "test3@gmail.com", PasswordHash = "password3", UserRole = "Senior" });
            _context.Add(new ApplicationUser { UserList = userTable, Id = "4", UserName = "Hatfield", Email = "test4@gmail.com", PasswordHash = "password4", UserRole = "Junior" });
            _context.Add(new ApplicationUser { UserList = userTable, Id = "5", UserName = "Dooyong", Email = "test5@gmail.com", PasswordHash = "password5", UserRole = "UnAuth" });

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone point out why I'm unable to save db after inserting the user's attributes?

P.S. The following is my ApplicationUser class.
namespace OA2.Domain.Auth

```
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string UserRole { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserList")]
        public int UserListId { get; set; }
        public virtual UserTable UserList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm using EF 5.0.4.

Comment: Hi @Taki, could you please share your ApplicationUser design and your DbContext? Besides what is the version of your ef core?

Comment: Hi @Rena. I've just edited my post upon your request! I'm using EF 5.0.4 . Thanks for having an interest :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix relations

```
public class UserTable
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public UserTable()
        {
            ApplicationUsers = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
        }

        [InverseProperty(nameof(ApplicationUser.UserTable ))]
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

    }

     public class ApplicationUser
    {
        
        .... another properties
       
        public int UserTableId {get; set;}

        [ForeignKey(nameof(UserTableId ))]
        [InverseProperty("ApplicationUsers")]
        public virtual UserTable UserTable { get; set; }

    }
```

code

```
var userTable=new UserTable();
_context.Add(new ApplicationUser { UserTable=userTable, Id = "1", UserName = "Taki", Email = "test1@gmail.com", PasswordHash = "password1", UserRole = "Super" });
_context.Add(new ApplicationUser { UserTable=userTable, Id = "2", UserName = "Akshdeep", Email = "test2@gmail.com", PasswordHash = "password2", UserRole = "Major" });
_context.Add(new ApplicationUser { UserTable=userTable, Id = "3", UserName = "Jin", Email = "test3@gmail.com", PasswordHash = "password3", UserRole = "Senior" });
_context.Add(new ApplicationUser { UserTable=userTable, Id = "4", UserName = "Hatfield", Email = "test4@gmail.com", PasswordHash = "password4", UserRole = "Junior" });
_context.Add(new ApplicationUser { UserTable=userTable, Id = "5", UserName = "Dooyong", Email = "test5@gmail.com", PasswordHash = "password5", UserRole = "UnAuth" });

 _context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I've followed exactly what you suggested. Indeed, it's something I've missed. But the problem isn't solved even after having 'InverseProperty' notation. I followed this link as well. https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I've edited my post with the current version of my code.